# Rust Rocket mismatched types

Tags: rust

I just copied the example from [rocket docs](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/#usage) and have error.

```rust
  #![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

  #[macro_use]
  extern crate rocket;

  #[get("/person/<name>?<age>")]
  fn person(name: String, age: u8) -> String {
      let mike = uri!(person: "Mike Smith", 28);

      assert_eq!(mike.to_string(), "/person/Mike%20Smith?age=28");
  }

  fn main() {
      rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![person]).launch();
  }
```

Error Message:

```sh
main.rs|7 col 37 error| mismatched types expected struct `std::string::String`, found () note: expected type `std::string::String` found type `()` [E0308]                         
main.rs|7 col 4 info| mismatched types implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression note: expected type `std::string::String` found type `()` [E0308]
```

Why copying from an example give me error?

And it's my first post :hurray:

Comment: Its certainly upsetting when documentation doesn't work. However, this is a pretty simple problem: `person` is declared to return a `String` but the body doesn't return anything. You can learn Rust by following the official links under "Getting Started" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info). Also, I'm having trouble finding this example. Could you provide a link to it?

Comment: https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/macro.uri.html here it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complaining because you have a return type specified, and not returning it.  When I ran this code the compiler gave a more helpful answer, and something that you should include next time in your question:

```sh
$> cargo run
. . .
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:37
  |
7 | fn person(name: String, age: u8) -> String {
  |    ------                           ^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found `()`
  |    |
  |    implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Either you want to return a `String` type, or swtich the return type to a function:

```rust
#[get("/person/<name>?<age>")]
fn person(name: String, age: u8) -> () {
    let mike = uri!(person: "Mike Smith", 28);
    assert_eq!(mike.to_string(), "/person/Mike%20Smith?age=28");

    // or leave the return type as string, but return a string
    //return name
}
```

Comment: Somehow is working, but with 'unused' age.
  `| fn person(name: String, age: u8) -> String {
  |                         ^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: _age`

Comment: It's telling you that you're not using the age variable and thus should consider making it private (_<name>) or remove it all together.